# npm full of errors I think I set it up wrong?

Tags: npm

Error output from request update:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo npm install request --save

> usb@1.2.0 install /home/pi/node_modules/usb
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download: https://github.com/tessel/node-usb/releases/download/1.2.0/usb_bindings-v1.2.0-node-v51-linux-arm.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for usb@1.2.0 and node@7.2.1 (node-v51 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/root/.node-gyp/7.2.1"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/home/pi/node_modules/usb/.node-gyp"
make: Entering directory '/home/pi/node_modules/usb/build'
make: *** No rule to make target '../.node-gyp/7.2.1/include/node/common.gypi', needed by 'Makefile'.  Stop.
make: Leaving directory '/home/pi/node_modules/usb/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.34-v7+
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/home/pi/node_modules/usb/src/binding/usb_bindings.node" "--module_name=usb_bindings" "--module_path=/home/pi/node_modules/usb/src/binding"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/pi/node_modules/usb
gyp ERR! node -v v7.2.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/home/pi/node_modules/usb/src/binding/usb_bindings.node --module_name=usb_bindings --module_path=/home/pi/node_modules/usb/src/binding' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/pi/node_modules/usb/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:885:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.34-v7+
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/home/pi/node_modules/usb/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/pi/node_modules/usb
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v7.2.1
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.30
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/home/pi/node_modules/usb/src/binding/usb_bindings.node --module_name=usb_bindings --module_path=/home/pi/node_modules/usb/src/binding' (1)
pi@1.0.0 /home/pi
└── request@2.79.0 

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: xpc-connection@~0.1.4 (node_modules/noble/node_modules/xpc-connection):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for xpc-connection@0.1.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"arm"})
npm WARN pi@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: usb@1.2.0 (node_modules/usb):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: usb@1.2.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
```

Comment: Did you every find a solution to this?  I am facing a similar issue.